# JBoss 6 Starrtup failed : HSQLDB - out of memory issue

Tags: out-of-memory, hsqldb, jboss6.x

Please explain why I am not able to start JBoss server if I am adding any EAR file. While starting I am getting an error like this:

> Deployment
>   "vfs:///D:/Servers/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/all/deploy/hsqldb-ds.xml"
>   is in error due to the following reason(s): java.sql.SQLException: Out
>   of Memory

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to find out the issue. The localDB.backup, localDB.data, localDB.lck, localDB.log,localDB.properties and localDB.script file will be saved in jboss6/server/all/data/hypersonic data. So delete all those files and restart the server. It will be perfect. The reason is that whenever we try to start the server it ll check this folder and try to load the previous deployed info from this backup files. So if any incomplete deployment will corrupt these files.